# push ViewController to CCScene Take moreTime And More Memory Uses?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Hello friends I am push `ViewController` to `CCscene` successfully but when I click on "Push Button" it takes 5-6 seconds to push to `CCScene`. Also, each time memory use increases. It's not smooth.

`ViewController` to `CCScene` push code as below:

```
CCDirectorIOS *director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

[director_ pushScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:director_ animated:YES];
```

I am using the above because each time I want to call `+(id)init` Method Of `CCScene`.

I am also use below mehod but that is not call +(id)init method each time

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[CCDirect SharedDirect] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is there any code in `viewWillAppear` of `CDDirectorIOS`? If yes, show that code too..

Comment: No,CCScene has Only +(id)init Method

Comment: I didn't ask about CCScene, I'm asking about `CCDirectorIOS(sharedDirector returning object`)? and also show `pushScene:` implementation..

Comment: Yes it return object of CCDirect

Comment: I think ,this problem occurs because of `pushScene`. see this explanation about pushScene http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_director.html#a548727f4d1521265d32abc2916f72f55

Comment: yes but use [self.navigationController pushViewController:[CCDirect SharedDirect] animated:YES]; it not occurs but at that time init is not call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44042/discussion-between-mani-and-kirit-modi)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run this:

```
[director_ pushScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
```

A new scene is created and pushed onto the scene stack. All previously existing scenes remain in memory. That explains the ever increasing memory usage. To fix this use `replaceScene:` instead.

If you do "shut down" the director when the view controller deallocates, then cocos2d will have to re-initialize itself every time, which is a time consuming process. More so the more textures you are loading in your scene. That would explain the delay between presenting view controllers.

I can't tell you why both occur without seeing more code. But I bet that either one of these two issues are at the heart of it.